# Filtering <li> From Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-lists

I have been trying to use this snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/1294/ and implement it within my own website, however, it does not seem to be working. The snippet I am using uses divs rather that lists. But, that should make no difference since I edited the script.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```js
   $("#da-thumbs :checkbox").click(function() {
       var filter = '.' + $("#da-thumbs :checkbox:checked").map(function() {
          return this.value;
      }).get().join(".");

      $('.category-container li').hide();
      $(filter).show();
    });
```

```html
 <div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="gallery-top heading margin-heading filter">
    <h3>FILTER</h3>
   </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 tags filters">
      <h4>Meal</h4>
<div class='checkbox'><input value='Breakfast' id='filter-Breakfast' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Breakfast'> Breakfast</label></div><div class='checkbox'><input value='Lunch' id='filter-Lunch' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Lunch'> Lunch</label></div><div class='checkbox'><input value='Dinner' id='filter-Dinner' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Dinner'> Dinner</label></div><div class='checkbox'><input value='Dessert' id='filter-Dessert' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Dessert'> Dessert</label></div><div class='checkbox'><input value='Light Bites' id='filter-Light Bites' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Light Bites'> Light Bites</label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <h4>Cuisine</h4>
<div class='checkbox'><input id='2' type='checkbox'><label for='Italian'> Italian</label></div><div class='checkbox'><input id='3' type='checkbox'><label for='Thai'> Thai</label></div><div class='checkbox'><input id='1' type='checkbox'><label for='Vegan'> Vegan</label></div>    </div>
    
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script>
  $(".filter").click(function(){
   $(".filters").slideToggle("fast");
   //if ( $('#filters').is(':hidden') ) {
    
   //}
  });
 </script>
 
 <!--banner-end-->
 <!--gallery-starts-->
 <div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="gallery-top heading">
    <h3>OUR RECIPES</h3>
   </div>
   <section>
    <ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs category-container">
     <li class="Dessert Italian">
      <a href="1" rel="title" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
       <img src="/images/Recipes/1/1.jpg" alt="" />
       <div>
        <h5>Lasagna </h5>
        <span>asagne originated in Italy, traditionally ascribed to the city of Naples (Campania), where the first modern recipe was created in the Middle Ages</span>
        <span class="skill">Skill: Easy</span>
        <span class="time">Time: 30 mins</span>
       </div>
      </a>
     </li>
          <li class="Dinner Italian Vegan">
      <a href="2" rel="title" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
       <img src="/images/Recipes/2/1.jpg" alt="" />
       <div>
        <h5>Vegan Spaghetti</h5>
        <span>asagne originated in Italy, traditionally ascribed to the city of Naples (Campania), where the first modern recipe was created in the Middle Ages</span>
        <span class="skill">Skill: Easy</span>
        <span class="time">Time: 30 mins</span>
       </div>
      </a>
     </li>
          <li class="Dinner Lunch Italian">
      <a href="3" rel="title" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
       <img src="/images/Recipes/3/1.jpg" alt="" />
       <div>
        <h5>Meat Spaghetti</h5>
        <span>asagne originated in Italy, traditionally ascribed to the city of Naples (Campania), where the first modern recipe was created in the Middle Ages</span>
        <span class="skill">Skill: Easy</span>
        <span class="time">Time: 30 mins</span>
       </div>
      </a>
     </li>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </ul>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#da-thumbs :checkbox` is empty because there are no `:checkbox` elements in `#da-thumbs`. Also, you have no value attributes on the "cuisine" section checkboxes, and the value is used as the string to filter by classname in the recipe section.

I removed `#da-thumbs` from the places you reference `:checkbox` and filled in the values for the cuisine checkboxes.

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  var filter = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(".");
  
  if (filter == '') {
    $('.category-container li').show();
  } else {
    $('.category-container li').hide();
    $('.'+filter).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gallery-top heading margin-heading filter">
      <h3>FILTER</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 tags filters">
        <h4>Meal</h4>
        <div class='checkbox'><input value='Breakfast' id='filter-Breakfast' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Breakfast'> Breakfast</label></div>
        <div class='checkbox'><input value='Lunch' id='filter-Lunch' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Lunch'> Lunch</label></div>
        <div class='checkbox'><input value='Dinner' id='filter-Dinner' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Dinner'> Dinner</label></div>
        <div class='checkbox'><input value='Dessert' id='filter-Dessert' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Dessert'> Dessert</label></div>
        <div class='checkbox'><input value='Light Bites' id='filter-Light Bites' type='checkbox'><label for='filter-Light Bites'> Light Bites</label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <h4>Cuisine</h4>
        <div class='checkbox'><input id='2' type='checkbox' value="Italian"><label for='Italian'> Italian</label></div>
        <div class='checkbox'><input id='3' type='checkbox' value="Thai"><label for='Thai'> Thai</label></div>
        <div class='checkbox'><input id='1' type='checkbox' value="Thai"><label for='Vegan'> Vegan</label></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(".filter").click(function() {
      $(".filters").slideToggle("fast");
      //if ( $('#filters').is(':hidden') ) {

      //}
    });
  </script>

  <!--banner-end-->
  <!--gallery-starts-->
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="gallery-top heading">
        <h3>OUR RECIPES</h3>
      </div>
      <section>
        <ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs category-container">
          <li class="Dessert Italian">
            <a href="1" rel="title" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
              <img src="/images/Recipes/1/1.jpg" alt="" />
              <div>
                <h5>Lasagna </h5>
                <span>asagne originated in Italy, traditionally ascribed to the city of Naples (Campania), where the first modern recipe was created in the Middle Ages</span>
                <span class="skill">Skill: Easy</span>
                <span class="time">Time: 30 mins</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="Dinner Italian Vegan">
            <a href="2" rel="title" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
              <img src="/images/Recipes/2/1.jpg" alt="" />
              <div>
                <h5>Vegan Spaghetti</h5>
                <span>asagne originated in Italy, traditionally ascribed to the city of Naples (Campania), where the first modern recipe was created in the Middle Ages</span>
                <span class="skill">Skill: Easy</span>
                <span class="time">Time: 30 mins</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="Dinner Lunch Italian">
            <a href="3" rel="title" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox">
              <img src="/images/Recipes/3/1.jpg" alt="" />
              <div>
                <h5>Meat Spaghetti</h5>
                <span>asagne originated in Italy, traditionally ascribed to the city of Naples (Campania), where the first modern recipe was created in the Middle Ages</span>
                <span class="skill">Skill: Easy</span>
                <span class="time">Time: 30 mins</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </ul>
      </section>
```

Comment: How do I make it so it shows all the list again when all the checkboxes become unticked?

Comment: For some reason the hyperlinks no wonder work on the lists, any idea why? Thanks once again :)

Comment: @DanSpedey not sure what you mean. If you mean the server error when you click on them, not sure why those pages have an error, I don't know anything about them.

Comment: As you can see here: http://www.happilycheddarafter.com/recipe-book/ When you click on one of the recipes, the link to take you to that page does not work - it just does nothing.

Comment: @DanSpedey I dunno, looks like you have some kind of click handler for those links that is throwing a bunch of 404 errors in the browser console.